# Как для onToggle() использовать setTimeout() React, chakra-ui

Tags: reactjs, nextjs

Критически важно вызвать функцию `onToggle()` внутри другой функции после 3 секунд

```js
export default function Home() {
  const { isOpen, onToggle } = useDisclosure() // Использую chakra-ui
  const send = () => {
    onToggle()
    // setTimeout(() => onToggle(), 3000)   нужно выполнить
  }
  return (
        <div>
      <Slide direction='top' in={isOpen} style={{ zIndex: 10 }}>
        <p>123</p>
      </Slide>
      <button onClick={() => send()}>Click</button>
    </div>
   )
}
```

Использование hook'ов невозможно, так как их нельзя использовать вне родительской функции. Пытался сделать вызов `onToggle()`, c помощью `useTimeout()`, но он начинает мгновенное исполнение, а мне нужно только при вызове функции `send()`.

Comment: если ты раскомментируешь строчку с setTimeout - то все будет работать

Comment: @Grundy Очень странно для меня, но ничего не происходит, даже ошибки

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Решил проблему добавив `onClose()` и `onOpen()`

```js
export default function Home() {
  const { isOpen, onOpen, onClose } = useDisclosure() // Использую chakra-ui
  const send = () => {
    onOpen()
    setTimeout(() => onClose(), 3000)
  }
  return (
        <div>
      <Slide direction='top' in={isOpen} style={{ zIndex: 10 }}>
        <p>123</p>
      </Slide>
      <button onClick={() => send()}>Click</button>
    </div>
   )
```